# Why does my binary file get rewritten each time?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to write a binary file with a dictionary of pattern objects. However, the problem I'm facing currently is that my binary file always just has one pattern object only. The **previous pattern object gets rewritten** by a new one whenever I add it to the dictionary.

I am not able to see how it's doing that as I serialize the entire dictionary after the data stream is created. So it should end up writing all the pattern objects to the binary file.

Here is the code snippet:

```
Pattern newPatternObject = new Pattern(filename, savedDistanceList, patternTangibleList);
PatternDictionary.Add(filename, newPatternObject);

IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
Stream stream = new FileStream("Pattern.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
formatter.Serialize(stream, PatternDictionary);
stream.Close();
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: My first guess would be that you are creating a new dictionary each time, but the code you've provided doesn't indicate either way.  Have you confirmed that the `Count` of the dictionary is what you think it is before serialising?

Comment: I don't know aything about C# but I assume that rather than `FileMode.Create` you want `FileMode.Append` .

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes I did check for the count and its a global dictionary, I just add pattern objects to it whenever a new one is created.

Comment: @Mort that works :D thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your FileMode.Create to FileMode.Append

Comment: I mean FileMode.Create to FileMode.Append

Comment: @Naaz Accept it as answer if it works and it is solution to your problem.